# Attach corrupted database

Tags: sql-server, corruption

In a little C# tool, I use an a mdf file to save my data.

The file became inconsistent, which isn't really a problem as there only a few changes since my last backup.

Anyway, I would still like to take a look at my last transaction to see what went wrong.

But I can't find a free tool to do so.

- ApexSQL requires an SQL Server connection.
- SysTool SQL Analyzer only allows for the first 50 rows, I have about 250.
- ::fn_dump again only on the SQL Server.

I have a running SQL Server available but can't attach the mdf file due to its corrupted state.

Is there a (free) way to view the log file? Doesn't need to be pretty, doesn't need special filters or search functions just plain and simple viewing.

Comment: If you need further experience or have some time to practice, you might want to tackle the database corruption challenge. You'll learn a few tricks doing so : https://stevestedman.com/server-health/database-corruption-challenge/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a dummy database as documented in:

[Creating, detaching, re-attaching, and fixing a SUSPECT database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/) by Paul Randal

This sometimes can "trick" the server into mounting a corrupt database.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

As database is in corrupted state then, the best way to get the data is restoring the DB from backup file.

**If database is in SUSPECT mode ;then, you can follow these steps:**
If your database is in SUSPECT state, then never detach it.

Run DBCC CHECKDB command to check the main reason of the corruption. You can possibly fix the corruption with one of these solutions:

- If the cause of corruption is a non-clustered index, then you can drop the index and recreate it.
- If the cause of the corruption is in a clustered index, then fix the index by using appropriate methods of repairing and/or restoring.